# how to Find $P_{tot}$ Given that $K_p = 28.5$ and the partial pressure at equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium, pressure

I have the equilibrium equation :

$4KO_2{_{(s)}} + 2CO_2{_{(g)}} \ce{<=>} 2K_2CO_3{_{(s)}} + 3O_2{_{(g)}}~~k_p = 28.5 ~at ~25C$.

Given that The partial Pressure of $CO_2$ is $0.191~atm$ at equilibrium Find the total pressure ($P_{tot})$.

so i constructed this :

$~~~~~~4KO_2{_{(s)}} + 2CO_2{_{(g)}} \ce{<=>} 2K_2CO_3{_{(s)}} + 3O_2{_{(g)}}$

$t_{int}~~$   ____       $~~~~~~~\frac{2191P_{tot}}{3000}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$____   $~~~~~~~~~~~~0$

$t_{eql}~~$   ____       $~~~~~~~\frac{191P_{tot}}{1000}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$____   $~~~~~~~~~~~~0.809P_{tot}$

so $K_p = \frac{[0.809P_{tot}]^3}{[0.191P_{tot}]^2} = 28.5 $

so $\fbox{$P_{tot}$ = 1.96365 atm}$

but my answer is wrong and i dont know why.
i also tried to calculate the total pressure at the initial state as an answer but that also gave wrong answer.

Comment: Bro pressure of $CO_2$ is 0.191 and pressure of $O_2$ is ($P_{tot}$-0.191)

Comment: i dont get you the partial pressure of $CO_2$ is $0.191 P_{tot}$  and so the partial pressure of $O_2$ is : $ P_{tot} - 0.191P_{tot} = 0.809P_{tot}$

Comment: The partial pressure of $CO_2$ is 0.191atm not 0.191$P_{tot}$ if you have not make any mistake in writing above question.

Comment: my bad but yes and so the pressure of $CO_2$ is what i wrote above

Comment: the result still the same its the concept

Comment: can someone solve this problem because i'v been trying to solve since yesterday

Comment: Let $P_{tot}$ - 0.191= x, then $x^3$ = 28.5(0.191)², this gives $P_{tot} approximately      1.2

Comment: it gave me a right answer , the question said that it was partial pressure but from your solution i understand that it was regular pressure of the gas . right ?

Comment: They both are same in the way you are treating regular pressure